# MVVM - get context in a Model class

Tags: java, android, mvvm, android-sqlite, viewmodel

I'm using MVVM to build my Android app and I need to connect the Model to a DB. Instead of Room I'm using the SQLiteOpenHelper and to make a connection to the DB I need the context. But since this is a non activity class I'm struggling to get it.
[image: mvvm]

My current solution looks as follows but I keep getting a memory leak warning.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private static MyApplication mContext;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mContext = this;
    }

    public static MyApplication getContext() {
        return mContext;
    }
}
```

Any better solution or best practice?

*edit: not using Dagger*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution works but you break the `Dependency Inversion` rule in MVVM pattern. So you should implement `Dependency Injection` pattern using constructor injection or frameworks like `Dagger` to pass the `context` to your model layer. Your memory leak is because of breaking this rule too and by implementing Dependency Injection there is no need for global variables with multiple access in different layers which can cause memory leaks.

Comment: I understand how the DI works, but how do I pass the context down to the model?

Comment: You could pass it from your View to the ViewModel and then in your ViewModel pass it to the Model using the constructor or even method parameter. Also, you could use dependency injection frameworks like Dagger to inject it directly. @dmak2709

Comment: My repository class is a singleton so again I'm still getting the same warning...

Comment: Sometimes Android Studio just shows warnings without considering your usage. Especially when you are using static global objects. Check your memory leaks with the LeakCanary library or suppress it. @dmak2709

Comment: Since I need the context in only one Repository method. Maybe it will be better if I pass it as a param, instead of having the class attribute?

Comment: Yes if you just use it in one method pass it as a method parameter instead of the constructor. @dmak2709

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the context to ViewModel using Factory, for Example:

```
public class ViewModelClass extends ViewModel{
      private Context context;
      public ViewModelClass(Context context){
           this.context = context;
      }
}
```

and the factory class

```
public class ViewModelFactory implements ViewModelProvider.Factory{
private Context context;

    public ViewModelFactory(Context context){
    this.context = context;
    }
    @Override
        public <T extends ViewModel> T create(Class<T> modelClass) {
            if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(ViewModelClass.class)) {
                return (T) new ViewModelClass(context);
            }
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown ViewModel class");
        }
   }
```

and when you used the ViewModel define the factory

```
ViewModelFactory viewModelFactory = new ViewModelFactory(context);
```

then pass it like this:

```
viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory).get(ViewModelClass.class)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you read the [View Model Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModel)
you will notice the very first line mentions [Known direct subclasses
AndroidViewModel](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/AndroidViewModel) which in turn has a public constructor that accepts the Application Context. Quote from the documentation:

> Application context aware ViewModel.
> Subclasses must have a constructor which accepts Application as the only parameter.